# Creating WSRP portlet with .net

Tags: .net, asp.net, web-services, wsrp

I'm working on a project where I need to create a WSRP portlet webservice with ASP.net.

My first question is what exactly is WSRP, and are there any good examples of it available? So far I have determined that it is a SOAP xml standard that defines how to create a portlet that can be embedded in an other portal. Is that correct?

Also I was planning on using MVC to do this. Is this a good idea?

Any thoughts on WSRP are welcome. I'm still trying to figure out exactly what it is and how to create it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WSRP was created not only to reuse backend code on different platforms, but to reuse some or all user interfase.

One of the best introductory pages [is this one from IBM](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/webservices/library/ws-wsrp/)

Comment: This was pretty much correct. We had a poor understanding of WSRP and chose not to use it for the project I was working on.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty keen to know how you've gotten on with this?
I've used MVC and netunity as my wsrp producer. 
Define each portlet in netunity and code it up to make a subsequent request to mvc running as a separate web app.
It works, but downside is that Netunity is pretty expensive, which is why it runs separately from our app, so we can have more load balanced apps behind less wsrp producers. And the extra request does add some overhead.